# D3 updating barchart using jquery $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am creating a barchart using D3 and am using jquery to select the bars. I have run into an issue I don't understand where I think I have selected a bar (rectangle) using $(this) and a console.log() statement seems to confirm this. However, I have issues getting certain functions (e.g. transition, style) to work -- the error message says they are not a function.

I have constructed a small example of the issues I am encountering below. Instead of a barchart, there are just two rectangles. I successfully change the width but cannot use transition to smooth this change and also cannot change the fill color using $(this).style.

Thanks for any help! Here is my code.

P.S. This is my first StackOverflow question so please let me know if I should have asked this question differently and/or if there is some convention I did not follow. I did a fairly exhaustive search over a couple of days regarding this issue and have really hit a wall. Thanks again!

```
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" id="this_svg">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" data-color="red"> </rect>
      <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="green" data-color="purple"></rect>
    </svg>

    <script>
        $ (document ).ready(function() {
            $svg = $("#this_svg")
            rcts = $svg.find("rect")
            // This Works Fine
            rcts.each(function() {
                $(this).attr("width", "500")
            });
            // This breaks (see error message):
            // Uncaught TypeError: $(...).transition is not a function
            rcts.each(function() {
                $(this).transition().duration(500).attr("width", "500")
            });
            //... and if this hadn't already broken, this next part would
            // break instead (see error message):
            // Uncaught TypError: $(...).style is not a function
            rcts.each(
                $(this).style("fill", function() {
                    return $(this).attr("data-color")
            }));
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Question: why do you have `d3js` as a tag if your code doesn't use d3? Btw, you're getting this error because `transition()` is a D3 function, not a jQuery one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3 !== jquery`, you can't call methods of `d3` selectors on `jquery` selectors.  **Note**, there is some overlap in method names (for instance they both have a `attr` method), but they are still not the same.

The easy fix to your troubles is to use a `d3` transition do:

```
 d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr("width", "500");
```

**but** it sounds like you need to read up to get a better understanding of the use cases for both libraries.  In my mind, when coding up anything to `d3`, don't even load `jquery`.  You don't need that `jquery` crutch, do it the `d3` way instead and you'll be less confused in the long run.

Comment: Thank you!! Quick question: my impression was that jquery allowed you to implement more efficient code through better selectors. I was mainly using jquery as a way to write shorter code that took less time to traverse the DOM as compared to D3. You're saying the code can be just as efficient using just D3?

Comment: @RyanBaxter-King, to answer you specific question, d3 and jquery are both using the same built-in selector methods under the hood, there's probably little performance difference there.  **But** you are asking the wrong question.  You should be focused on writing clean code that's easy to read, understand and refactor.  If you want to build a `d3` based visualization, you need d3.  IMHO, mixing jquery on top just leads to less maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

If you created your bar chart using D3 you should select its elements using the same D3. It makes very little sense selecting those elements with jQuery.

Your code will not work because neither `transition()` nor `style` are jQuery functions. That being said, you should use D3 to manipulate your elements:

```js
var rects = d3.selectAll("rect");
rects.transition().duration(1000).attr("width", 500).attr("fill", function(){
 return d3.select(this).attr("data-color");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="1000" id="this_svg">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" data-color="red"> </rect>
      <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="green" data-color="purple"></rect>
    </svg>
```